# Dynamic SQL SELECT column names and related data using UNPIVOT

Tags: select, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

I have a table called `PERSONNELSERVICELEVELS` with general info such as `ID` and `Name`, but also many columns identified as `ServiceLevel%` as follows:

```
Person_ID  Last_Name  First_Name  ServiceLevel1  ServiceLevel2  ServiceLevel3  etc.
---------  ---------  ----------  -------------  -------------  -------------
222        Doe        John        4              5              NULL  
555        Doe        Jane        2              6              9
```

I would like to create a `SELECT` statement to produce this output:

```
Person_ID  Last_Name  First_Name  ServiceLevel  Level
---------  ---------  ----------  ------------  ----- 
222        Doe        John        ServiceLevel1 4
222        Doe        John        ServiceLevel2 5
222        Doe        John        ServiceLevel3 NULL
555        Doe        Jane        ServiceLevel1 2
555        Doe        Jane        ServiceLevel2 6
555        Doe        Jane        ServiceLevel3 9
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell us what RDBMS you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn columns into rows, so to speak, you might use a `UNION`, as in:

```
select Person_ID, Last_Name, First_Name, 'ServiceLevel1' as ServiceLevel, ServiceLevel1 as [Level]
from PERSONNELSERVICELEVELS
union all
select Person_ID, Last_Name, First_Name, 'ServiceLevel2' as ServiceLevel, ServiceLevel2 as [Level]
from PERSONNELSERVICELEVELS
union all
-- etc.
```

I'm using `union all` here because union implicitly runs a distinct operation as well, and that is unnecessary here.

You can also do this type of thing with [`UNPIVOT`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mab/archive/2008/06/16/sql-server-2005-unpivot-command-changings-columns-to-rows-normalizing.aspx).

Comment: The table was imported from an Excel spreadsheet where there could be 50 to 100 columns. Is there a way to not alias or explicitly define the column name output (ex. Servicelevel1, ServiceLevel2, etc.) but rather list the column_name defined by the information_schema.columns?

select [column_name] from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'PERSONNELSERVICELEVELS'

Comment: It would not be as straightforward, but you could potentially use the system catalogs and dynamic SQL to build the query on the fly.  In the case of pivoting, this often makes sense because you may not know the number of columns in advance.  With unpivoting, however, you would seem to know which columns you are creating rows for.  Even with calling information_schema, you'd have to define a where clause to pick those column names.

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction Tim. I do have a where clause and using unpivoting came up with exactly what I was looking for. Syntax as follows:

Comment: `declare @cname nvarchar(max)
SELECT  @cname = 
STUFF((SELECT  ', ' +CAST('['+[COLUMN_NAME]+']' AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
    FROM  information_schema.columns
    where table_name = 'PERSONNELSERVICELEVELS' and column_name like 'ServiceLevel%'
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)') 
            ,1,1,'') 
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'SELECT Person_ID, Last_Name, First_Name, ServiceLevel, Level
FROM 
(
  SELECT Person_ID, Last_Name, First_Name, '+@cname+'
  FROM PERSONNELSERVICELEVELS
) MyTable
UNPIVOT
(Level FOR ServiceLevel IN ('+@cname+'))AS MyUnPivot'
exec sp_executesql @sql`